# Cost function in OLS linear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, loss-functions

I'm a bit confused with a lecture on linear regression given by Andrew Ng on Coursera about machine learning. There, he gave a cost function that minimises the sum-of-squares as:

$$ \frac{1}{2m} \sum _{i=1}^m \left(h_\theta(X^{(i)})-Y^{(i)}\right)^2 $$

I understand where the $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from. I think he did it so that when he performed derivative on the square term, the 2 in the square term would cancel with the half. But I don't understand where the $\frac{1}{m}$ come from.

Why do we need to do $\frac{1}{m}$? In the standard linear regression, we don't have it, we simply minimise the residuals. Why do we need it here?

Comment: 1/2m helps to find the average error per data point and m represents total observations or number of observations.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As you seem to realize, we certainly don't need the $1/m$ factor to get linear regression.  The minimizers will of course be exactly the same, with or without it.  One typical reason to normalize by $m$ is so that we can view the cost function as an approximation to the "generalization error", which is the expected square loss on a randomly chosen new example (not in the training set):

Suppose $(X,Y),(X^{(1)},Y^{(1)}),\ldots,(X^{(m)},Y^{(m)})$ are sampled i.i.d. from some distribution. Then for large $m$ we expect that
$$
\frac{1}{m} \sum _{i=1}^m \left(h_\theta(X^{(i)})-Y^{(i)}\right)^2 \approx   \mathbb{E}\left(h_\theta(X)-Y\right)^2.
$$

More precisely, by the Strong Law of Large Numbers, we have
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{1}{m} \sum _{i=1}^m \left(h_\theta(X^{(i)})-Y^{(i)}\right)^2 =  \mathbb{E}\left(h_\theta(X)-Y\right)^2
$$
with probability 1.

Note: Each of the statements above are for any particular $\theta$, chosen without looking at the training set.  For machine learning, we want these statements to hold for some $\hat{\theta}$ chosen based on its good performance on the training set.  These claims can still hold in this case, though we need to make some assumptions on the set of functions $\{h_\theta \,|\, \theta \in \Theta\}$, and we'll need something stronger than the Law of Large Numbers.

Comment: @StudentT  This is probably the best reason for using the average error over the total.  My explanation is really just a surface level consequence of DavidR's deeper reason.

Answer (score 30):

You don't *have* to.  The loss function has the same minimum whether you include the $\frac{1}{m}$ or suppress it.  If you include it though, you get the nice interpretation of minimizing (one half) the *average* error per datapoint.  Put another way, you are minimizing the error *rate* instead of the total error.

Consider comparing the performance on two data sets of differing sizes.  The raw sum of squared errors are not directly comparable, as larger datasets tend to have more total error just due to their  size.  On the other hand, the average error per datapoint **is**.

> Can you elaborate a bit?

Sure.  Your data set is a collection of data points $\{ x_i, y_i \}$.  Once you have a model $h$, the least squares error of $h$ on a single data point is

$$ (h(x_i) - y_i)^2 $$

this is, of course, different for each datapoint.  Now, if we simply sum up the errors (and multiply by one half for the reason you describe) we get the total error

$$ \frac{1}{2} \sum_i (h(x_i) - y_i)^2 $$

but if we divide by the number of summands we get the *average* error per data point

$$ \frac{1}{2m} \sum_i (h(x_i) - y_i)^2 $$

The benefit of the average error is that if we have *two* datasets $\{ x_i, y_i \}$ and $\{ x'_i, y'_i \}$ of *differeing sizes*, then we can compare the average errors but not the total errors.  For if the second data set is, say, ten times the size of the first, then we would expect the total error to be about ten times larger for the same model.  On the other hand, the average error divides out the effect of the size of the data set, and so we would expect models of similar performance to have the similar average errors on different data sets.

Comment: I can kind of follow you, can you elaborate a bit? Sorry, I'm new to machine learning!

Comment: @StudentT I attempted a clarification in my answer.

Comment: The same also applies if you happen to experiment with the mini-batch size when doing stochastic gradient descent, which is the most common type of linear gradient descent when working with large datasets: you can more easily compare the error.